# How do I efficiently make use of the result of a function call in a MySQL query multiple times without calling the function multiple times?

Tags: mysql, function, call, reusability, processing-efficiency

I have an SQL query like:

```
SELECT blah
  FROM table
 WHERE field1 % functCall(otherField1, otherField2) = 0
    OR field2 % functCall(otherField1, otherField2) = 0
    OR field3 % functCall(otherField1, otherField2) = 0
```

Is there a way that I can only call functCall once, reusing it's result in the other two comparisons?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL will automatically optimize your query so that the function is only called once and the result will be reused.

If you want to avoid the repeated code you can evaluate the function in a derived table and then query that.

```
SELECT blah
FROM
(
    SELECT 
        blah, field1, field2, field3,
        functCall(otherField1, otherField2) AS f
    FROM your_table
) T1
WHERE field1 % f = 0
   OR field2 % f = 0
   OR field3 % f = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the result of the function in a variable first the use it in your query.

Comment: I wanted to do that, but that doesn't exactly make sense.  The values for otherField1 and otherField2 correspond to values specific to the current row being tested as the query scans the rows in my table.  If I were to make a variable to store the output of the function, I would have to make one for every row.  Right?

Answer (score 0):

Use a sub-query in the from clause, then check the condition in the outer query:

```
 SELECT blah
 FROM
   (select functCall(f1, f2) as fc, f1, f2, f3 from table) as t 
 WHERE f1 % fc = 0
    OR f2 % fc = 0
    OR f3 % fc = 0
```